# Unbound Error when posting data to JSONRPC

Tags: python, json, rpc

When making my RPC server allow external connections and posting data to the server, e.g

```
{ 
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "params": { "token":"my_token_here" },
  "method": "listShards",
  "id": "1.0"
}
```

I recieve this error. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'params' referenced before assignment`

Here is my code. http://pastebin.com/NzkfEYn9

Thank you.

*edit: I've looked around the internet and most answers don't help me or my situation.*

Comment: You do not define `params` when `request.params` is `dict`

Comment: Do you mind making that an answer so I can tick it off?

Comment: Please don't just link to code at an external site. If that site is unavailable your question looses all value.